# Ant PDE Tests Run with JUnit4

Tags: ant, junit4, pde

I am trying to automate pde tests, using pde-maven-plugin, maven calls, or ant tasks. I followed instructions from the article [Automating Eclipse PDE Unit Tests using Ant](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-PDEJUnitAntAutomation/index.html) to create the test.xml

Tests failed, first because No Tests Found

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in com.example.TestSuite
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
```

I searched and found that I should use `JUnit4Adapter`, but doing that I got `ClassCastException`, here's the stack trace

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter cannot be cast to junit.framework.Test
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestLoader.getTest(JUnit3TestLoader.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit3TestLoader.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.RemotePluginTestRunner.main(RemotePluginTestRunner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.CoreTestApplication.run(CoreTestApplication.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1287)
```

Here's my plugin dependencies:

```
Require-Bundle: 
 org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.jdt.core;bundle-version="3.4.2",
 org.eclipse.jdt.launching;bundle-version="3.4.1",
 org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.4.1",
 org.apache.xerces;bundle-version="2.9.0",
 org.junit4;bundle-version="4.3.1"
```

and the test class

```
package com.example;

import junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter;
import junit.framework.Test;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses( { SimpleTests.class})
public class TestSuite {

    public static Test suite() {

        return new JUnit4TestAdapter(TestSuite.class);
    }

}
```

any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fixed by adding next lines when invoking org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main:

```
<arg line="-testLoaderClass org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader"/>
<arg line="-loaderpluginname org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime"/>
```

Here's the full java ant task:

```
<java dir="${plugin.dir}"  
    fork="yes"
    classname="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main"
    classpathref="equinox.launcher.class.path"
    jvm="${jvm}">
    <arg line="-application ${application}"/>
    <arg line="-data ${test.reports.dir}/output/ws"/>
    <arg line="-port ${pde.test.port}"/>
    <arg line="-dev bin -clean -debug"/>
    <arg line="-testpluginname ${plugin.name}"/>
    <arg line="-testLoaderClass org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader"/>
    <arg line="-loaderpluginname org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime"/>
    <arg line="-classnames ${test.classes.list}"/>
    <jvmarg line="${vmargs}"/>
</java>
```

Comment: A careful look at the stacktrace reveals why this helps.  Notice the Exception comes from `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestLoader.getTest(JUnit3TestLoader.java:108)`, emphasis on the **junit.runner.junit3** part.  Adding the two argument lines requests that JUnit4Launcher be used instead of JUnit3.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as Noura and tried the fix they provided, which, unfortunately, only solved part of the problem.  Instead of throwing the aforementioned `ClassCastException`, I got `junit4 java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods`, despite my 29 tests being carefully annotated with `@Test`.

After a few hours of searching (and only finding really old bugs back when JUnit 4 was new) and experimenting ([this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157118/no-runnable-methods-while-running-test-case-run-as-junit-plugin-test) didn't help either), I discovered the second part of my fix was related to the class path.

I had defined my classpath (which was used to launch `PDETestResultsCollector`, `PDETestPortLocator` and the test plugin) to be:

```
<path id="test.class.path">
   <pathelement location="build/my-bundled-jar-with-tests.jar" /> <!-- contains my app and the PDE* helper classes -->
   <fileset dir="${test.eclipse.dir}/plugins">
      <include name="org.junit_4.*/**/junit.jar" />
      <include name="org.hamcrest.core_*.jar" />
      <include name="org.apache.ant_*/**/ant.jar" />
      <include name="org.apache.ant_*/**/ant-junit.jar" />
      <include name="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar" />
      <include name="org.eclipse.jdt.junit_*.jar" />
      <include name="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core_*.jar" />
      <include name="org.eclipse.equinox.common_*.jar" />
      <include name="org.eclipse.debug.core_*.jar" />
      <include name="org.eclipse.osgi_*.jar" />
      <include name="org.eclipse.core.resources_*.jar" />
      <include name="org.eclipse.core.runtime_*.jar" />
      <include name="org.eclipse.core.jobs_*.jar" />
      <include name="org.eclipse.ui.workbench_*.jar" />
      <include name="org.eclipse.swt_*.jar" />
      <include name="org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_*.jar" />
      <include name="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_*.jar" />
   </fileset>
</path>
```

and launched it like:

```
<java classpathref="test.class.path" classname="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main" fork="yes" dir="${basedir}" >
   <arg line="-application org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.uitestapplication" />
   <arg line="-data reports/output/ws" />
   <arg line="-dev bin -clean -port ${pde.test.port}" />
   <arg line="-testApplication org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" />
   <arg line="-testpluginname my-bundled-plugin-with-tests" />
   <arg line="-testLoaderClass org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader" />
   <arg line="-loaderpluginname org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime" />
   <arg line="-classnames TestAllMyCode" />
</java>
```

As it turns out, having `build/my-bundled-jar-with-tests.jar` on the classpath confused the test runner, so I had to make a new jar that contained just class files for `PDETestListener`, `PDETestPortLocator` and `PDETestResultsCollector` (called pde-test.jar).  My fixed path was:

```
<path id="test.class.path">
   <pathelement location="build/pde-test.jar" /> <!-- fixed the problem -->
   <fileset dir="${test.eclipse.dir}/plugins">
      <include name="org.junit_4.*/**/junit.jar" />
      <include name="org.hamcrest.core_*.jar" />
      ... <!-- same as before -->
```

And all 29 tests were found and ran.