# No runnable methods while running Test case run as Junit Plugin test

Tags: eclipse-plugin, junit4

I have created test case for a eclipse RCP application:

```
@Test
public final void testIsCacertsFileExist() {
    try {//URL url = new URL("https://server/web/services/WO");
    // System.out.println(url.getPort());
    URL url1 = new URL("http://server/web/services/WO");
    System.out.println(url1.getPort());
    CertificateHandler.addCertToKeyStore(
        "http://server/web/services/WO");", 443);
    File file = new File("cacerts");
    Assert.assertTrue(file.exists());
    readCertificates(file);
} catch (ConnectionException e) {
    fail(e.getMessage());
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

I am using `@Test` annotation.
In Eclipse I am running `run as > Junit Plugin test`.
Still I am getting below error:

```
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:177)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:122)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:269)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:13)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.RemotePluginTestRunner.main(RemotePluginTestRunner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.PlatformUITestHarness$1.run(PlatformUITestHarness.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at com.ibm.stp.Application.start(Application.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution to my question.
I delete the project from workspace. Created newly checkout the code from repository.
 junit-4.3.1.jar added in the class-path.
Opened the plugin.xml in dependency tab. under required plugins click on add button
type in the search org.junit. add the latest one in my eclipse (Indigo) org.junit(4.8.2.v4_8_2_v20110321-1705) and it display as org.junit(4.8.2).

Modification in files:
.classpath - added "junit-4.3.1.jar" entry
MANIFEST.MF - Require-Bundle: ,org.junit;bundle-version="4.8.2" got added due to change in plugin.xml.

Thanks,
Anand

Comment: For me, just adding the org.junit bundle to the manifest's dependencies tab was the answer. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Is this code itself also contained either in a test plugin or a plugin fragment (extending the plugin to be tested)? You cannot just have a Java class in a normal Java project for a plugin test.

Comment: This is normal test class but under Same plug in project as normal practice. We have a plugin project under that 2 source folders src, test. src have actual plugin code, test have the test Junit classes. It is a simple POJO class. One test method with @Test annotation.