# JUnit: No runnable tests in Eclipse. but works with maven

Tags: java, junit, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-pde

JUnit gives me "No runnable tests" when run under Eclipse, but works fine in the maven build.

I had a working test fragment, and then let the host plugin extend an extension point. This implies i need to use "Run an Plugin Test", otherwise the wiring won't work. Suddenly the test won't execute anymore. Using Maven/Tycho, however, works as expected.

Note that i do have junit as required bundle and that the test class used to work before i added the extension.

Any experience with similar problems?

Comment: Can be related to:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157118/no-runnable-methods-while-running-test-case-run-as-junit-plugin-test

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks, the suggested solution is not new to me, sadly enough fails in this case though. What is weird here is that the tests run fine outside of eclipse, so i guess the OSGi container i get by eclipse is not the same as the one i get from tycho (or surefire, that is).

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier for you to switch to pax-exam it's a osgi test framework working with junit and will work with eclipse and maven